# Get/set ServletRequest attributes from ActionContext

Tags: struts2, actioncontext

I need to set a `ServletRequest` attribute within a Struts2 interceptor (not action class).

Does the `ActionContext` expose a `Map<String, Object>` to control request attributes, like it does for session attributes?

I see `ActionContext` implements a map. Is the `ActionContext` itself a wrapper for the request attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code that is not inside an action class (`RequestAware` should be used for action classes), Struts2 can expose the servlet request attributes as a Map.  They are accessible with:

```
Map request = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().get("request");
```

See [Strus2 documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/accessing-application-session-request-objects.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The `ActionContext` contains a request key that holds the request object. To answer you question: no the `ActionContext` is not a wrapper for request, however the request in Struts2 is a wrapper for the servlet request.

You can get the `request` from the action context like

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

That way is useful in interceptors, but in action better to implement `ServletRequestAware`

```
protected HttpServletRequest request;

public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
  this.request = request;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for the request **attributes**, not **parameters**

Comment: I'm going with my answer below: it shows how to get only the request attribute map (rather than the entire servlet request object).

Comment: Ok, but your answer doesn't answer the question, which you probably don't understand yourself. Note, that to use such hardcoded values in the code is discoveraged. Also the context keys like `request` is not accessible by OGNL. Disclosing it might cause a security problems to your application.

Comment: To address your points... 'Hardcoded value is bad': I cited the approach with Struts2 documentation.  '`request` not accessible by OGNL': why does that matter?  Why are you bringing up OGNL?  'Security problems': explain.  My approach below is preferred because it avoids exposing the servlet API.  If you read the link, you will see it specifically says that your answer `ServletActionContext.getRequest()` isn't recommended, and that my approach is preferred.