# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException when submitting a form in Struts 2

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

This is my code I had written a logic to fetch the `username` and `password` from and database and after login the login time and logout time should enter into the database the time should be taken from the system

**action class:**

```
public class Login {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String login_time;
    private String logout_time;
    private String status;
    private String late;
    //getters and setters

 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 public String execute(ServletRequest req) throws Exception,SQLException{
int i=0;
    try{
        SessionUtils su = new SessionUtils(); 
        HttpSession session  =((Request) req).getSession();
        String hql="select * from login where username='"+username+"'and      
password='"+password+"'";           
        
        Query query1=((SessionUtils) session).createQuery(hql);
        query1.setParameter(1,getUsername());
        query1.setParameter(2,getPassword());
        
        int result = query1.executeUpdate();
        while(i!=0)
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd 
 =req.getRequestDispatcher("DailyInOut.jsp");
            return  hql;
        }
         } catch (Exception e) 
         {
             return late;
         }
    return status;
   }

  public String chandu(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res) throws      
  Exception,SQLException{
int j=0;
try
{
    java.util.Date myDate = new java.util.Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
    String strDates1 = formatter.format(myDate);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    SessionUtils su = new SessionUtils(); 
    String hql="update attendance  where date='"+strDates1+"' name='"+username+"' 
   login='"+login_time+"' logout='"+logout_time+"' status='"+status+"' 
 late='"+late+"'";
    
    HttpSession session  =((Request) req).getSession();
    Query query2=((SessionUtils) session).createQuery(hql);
    session.setAttribute("date", strDates1);
    session.setAttribute("login_time",login_time);
    session.setAttribute("logout_time",logout_time);
    session.setAttribute("status",status);
    session.setAttribute("late",late);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int result = query2.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(" update row updated");
    if(j!=0)
    {
    System.out.println("success1");
    return "success";
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.getMessage();
}
System.out.println("failure page");
return "failure";
}
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">

    <struts>
        <package namespace="/" name="packageOne" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="login" class="com.tribro.chandu.Login" method="post">
                <result name="success">DailyInOut.jsp</result>
                </action>
           </package>
    </struts>
```

**logina.jsp**

```
    <html>
   <head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="cyan" text="magenta">
  <form action="login" method="execute">
  <img src="WebContent/Images/java.jpg" height="80"/>
   <pre><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right"><font size="4">Welcome to TRIBRO     
 Limited</font></marquee><br/></pre>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <div>
  <img src="WebContent/Images/banner.png" height="300" width="900"></img>
  </div>
  </td>
  <td>
  <div>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
 <h4>Login Form</h4>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <h4>Username :</h4>
 </td>
 <td>
 <h4><input type="text" name="Username"/></h4>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>
 <h4>password:</h4>
 </td>
 <td>
 <h4><input type="password" name="password"/></h4>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
 <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But I am getting an error as

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.tribro.chandu.Login.post()
```

Comment: your code is excessively long

Comment: yes sir as this i am now to struts2 i had to complete my project with in a short span so i tried many ways but struct all time with the same error sir

Comment: Method in struts.xml isn't http method, but action class method.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form it has an incorrect method

> ```
> <form action="login" method="execute">
> ```

In the action mapping you have configured the method `post()` will be mapped to the `login` action. But, your action class doesn't have such method. If you change this mapping to

```
<action name="login" class="com.tribro.chandu.Login">
```

this will map to the `execute()` method by default. This method you should create in the action class. It has different signature which has *not* any parameters.

If you need to know how to get servlet objects such as `HttpServletRequest` then you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21292411/573032) answer.

> You can get the request from the action context like
>
> ```
> HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
> ```
>
> That way is useful in interceptors, but in action better to implement `ServletRequestAware`
>
> ```
> protected HttpServletRequest request;
>
> public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
>  this.request = request;
> }
> ```

Comment: sir,thank you but i used this before 
     if i used this tag i am getting the Exception as java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.tribro.chandu.Login.execute()

Comment: What is the name of the class you have posted, isn't it a `Login` class?

Comment: sir my class name is Login class only

Comment: sir,actually my need to compare the username and password from the values in the database if login success then the login time logout time and by how much the employee is late to login and this must be placed in the database of attendance but i am getting 500 eroors from 4 days

Comment: There are many ways to do that you can check the online tutorials or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17898392/573032) answer.

Answer (score 0):

> but I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.tribro.chandu.Login.post()`

- This makes me think you have written `method="post"` a `<s:submit/>` tag (or in struts.xml):

  ```xml
  <s:form action="login">
      <s:submit method="post" />
  </s:form>
  ```

  where `method` refers to an Action method, not to an HTTP method (like in `<s:form />`).
  Then remove method from the submit tag, and leave it on the form:

  ```xml
  <s:form action="login" method="post">
      <s:submit />
  </s:form>
  ```

> if i used this tag i am getting the Exception as `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.tribro.chandu.Login.execute()`

- You are putting parameters in your Action methods:

  ```xml
  public String execute(ServletRequest req) throws Exception,SQLException{
  ```

  this is not how it works, Action methods have no arguments, the parameters are passed through getters and setters, including ServletRequest and ServletResponse ([read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19540712/1654265)).

  Then rewrite your methods as:

  ```xml
  public String execute() throws Exception{
  ```

  and they will be found by Struts.